# SQLAlchemy delete() records in session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This question has been asked before but I didn't manage to find an answer that helps me achieve what I want to do. Here is a code sample

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine, autoflush=False)
session = Session()
```

and later on

```
session.query(StockPrices)\
    .filter(StockPrices.date >= new_data_min_date)\
    .filter(StockPrices.date <= new_data_max_date)\
    .delete(synchronize_session='fetch')

session.flush()
```

Afterwards I do a pandas `pd.read_sql(query.statement, session.bind)` with the query having a select statement on the `StockPrices` table. Unfortunately I still get the deleted records back. Most posts say you should `commit()` to get the records into the database. However, this is not what I want. What I am trying to achieve is to get the modified records from the session (i.e. whatever the table had minus the deleted records) for additional processing. As you would expect, there is a case later on to decide whether to `commit()` the whole thing as an atomic operation or `rollback()`. By committing after the `delete()` you are losing the ability of rolling back your changes if you change your mind later on.

Any ideas how I could go about it other than doing everything in pandas land before a final SQL query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `autoflush=False` so that changes are automatically flushed before next query.

[Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.params.autoflush)

Comment: OK I'll try that although I am flushing manually after the delete(), wouldn't that be enough in this case?